# Transaction Control in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a requirement to insert parent record and child records from LWC. I was plannign to use createRecord API of LWC and use childrelationship tag of record object to create in one call. However, it seems 'childrelationship' is not working. Getting error

> "Error on parameter recordInput:
> java://sfdc.uisdk.connect.api.input.RecordInputRepresentation"

If I create via two call to createRecord, how can I rollback parent record when childrecord fails to create.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to implement transaction control across multiple transactions in Salesforce. You'll have to write an Apex method to handle creating multiple records and rolling back the transaction on failure.